# Não consigo reinstalar wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Tenho um servidor ***vhost nginx*** chamado **site-responsivo.test** segue abaixo a configuração

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site-responsivo.test;
    root /home/rafaelejosi/www/projetos/site-responsivo.test/; 

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    #Este fuciona no link http://site-responsivo.test/wordpress/
    location /wordpress {
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    #O site original esta quebrado com erro no nginx 403 Forbidden http://site-responsivo.test/

    location /php {
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log on;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/site-responsivo.test-error.log error ;
    rewrite_log on;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

sabendo que a estrutura do diretório é essa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

qual a maneira certa de configurar esse vhost para que os dois funcionem?

Comment: Está dando erro em `http://site-responsivo.test/` ou `http://site-responsivo.test/php` ? Caso seja no primeiro: existe algum arquivo de *index* na pasta `site-responsivo.test`?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr nesse http://site-responsivo.test/ mas agora percebi o erro tudo foi movido para esse http://site-responsivo.test/php e nesse ta funcionando normal kkk, mas nem me liguei

Comment: @ValdeirPsr mas aproveitando a oportunidade as paginas na versão http://site-responsivo.test/php funcionam normal, http://site-responsivo.test/wordpress, onde tenho o mesmo menu não esta linkando para as demais paginas da file not found, vo ver se consigo publicar o site em algum servidor tem alguma sugestão de host-free que de pra subir wordpress e a versão que esta no php?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr a proposito tem como programar um redirecionamento para quando se digitar o http://site-responsivo.test ir automaticamente para http://site-responsivo.test/php ignorando o 404 mesmo na instalação local?

Comment: Como você duplicou o site, pode ser que seja necessário verificar as configurações no banco de dados.

Comment: E para corrigir o erro `404` (em `http://site-responsivo.test/`), você pode usar `rewrite` ou `try_files /php/index.php?$args`